# Failed to start jupyter kernel , Blocking cross orogin

Tags: jupyter, conda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

i have been trying to run jupyter notebook as below . but the kernel does not start and is stuck on : "kernel starting , please wait "

The terminal error looks like this :

```
[W 23:21:13.712 NotebookApp] Blocking Cross Origin API request for /api/config/tree.  Origin: http://localhost, Host: localhost:8888
[W 23:21:13.712 NotebookApp] Not Found
[W 23:21:13.714 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/config/tree?_=1658775073316 (127.0.0.1) 3.620000ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
```

and goes like that on and on

i have used diffrent browsers but it still doesnt work

Comment: Have you tried the solutions [highlighted here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1804)?

Comment: yes @Wayne but it doesnt work

Comment: Is this just a local installation?

Comment: hi @Wayne i dont understand your quastion , but i have installed jupyter using conda on wsl

Comment: And you are physically working the machine? It isn't something remote?

Comment: hi @Wayne yes i am working on it in my machine

Comment: So I think the solutions I originally pointed to probably cover this? You tried each and all those solutions there? There's several suggestions. You've tried a different browser?

Comment: @Wayne , i have tried this with chrome , firefox , opera

Comment: Do you have a `jupyter_notebook.config.py` file? See [here](https://github.com/twosigma/beakerx/issues/1963#issuecomment-334721791).

Comment: yes @Wayne and i have worked on it ( changed some stuff and etc ) like changing : c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = '*' , but didnt work